# Python does an indentation of the ): at the end of a function follow the pep8 style?

Tags: python, pep8

For an example function declaration:

```
def foo(
        long_parameter_name_1, long_parameter_name_2 = "default value var 2",
        long_parameter_name_3 = "default value var 3", long_parameter_name_4 = "default value var 4"
        ):
```

Does the above method of function declaration follow the pep8 style guidelines as a modified version of the below function definition in order to handle parameters for lines of over 80 characters? I find it more readable for long lines with default values but the pep8 style guide did not specify this condition.

```
def foo(long_parameter_name_1, long_parameter_name_2 = "default value var 2",
        long_parameter_name_3 = "default value var 3", long_parameter_name_ = "default value var 4"):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PEP-8 allows both; see the last section of the [discussion of indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation). However, it also recommends *no* spaces around the `=` in the keyword arguments, and it does not require quite so much indentation for the parameters. Indentation should match, but if the first parameter is on a new line, it need not be indented past the opening `(`.

Either

```
def foo(
    long_parameter_name_1, long_parameter_name_2="default value var 2",
    long_parameter_name_3="default value var 3", long_parameter_name_4="default value var 4"
    ):
```

or

```
def foo(
    long_parameter_name_1, long_parameter_name_2="default value var 2",
    long_parameter_name_3="default value var 3", long_parameter_name_4="default value var 4"):
```

is acceptable.

---

I would go one step farther, though, and recommend that in either case you limit yourself to one parameter per line.

```
def foo(
    long_parameter_name_1,
    long_parameter_name_2="default value var 2",
    long_parameter_name_3="default value var 3",
    long_parameter_name_4="default value var 4"
    ):
```

or

```
def foo(
    long_parameter_name_1,
    long_parameter_name_2="default value var 2",
    long_parameter_name_3="default value var 3",
    long_parameter_name_4="default value var 4"):
```

but with a preference for the first. (In the first case, you may also wish to include an optional trailing `,` after the last argument, to simplify diffs should you never add or remove a parameter.)